# Command line option to get tree view structure of LaTeX project

Tags: tools, robust-commands

I would like to get a tree-view of a latex project showing things like sections, chapters, figures.

```
- Table of contents
- Introduction (1.0)
--- fig 1  fig one title
--- fig 2   fig two title
- Second section (2.0)
--- fig 3 fig three title
- First Subsection in section 2 (2.1)
- Conclusion (3.0)
- References (4.0)
```

Is there a nice command line tool which is available for this such as texcount is available for wordcounts.

Comment: Probably, but… where you want that tree to be displayed? If it's in a terminal and you're using Unix, then `tree` is your friend to list your files (but then you'll have to put your figures in separate files). If it's in an IDE as TexStudio, then by playing a bit with the options, you should be able to do that too. If it's in your document, you could achieve that by modifying the `tableofcontents` command, I guess.

Comment: @Clément: I don't believe `tree` is correct here. I think, the tool should analyze the `.toc` and `.tof` files, most likely?

Comment: I have modified the example a bit. I was looking for the structure LaTeX see's it as via a unix command line option rather than a Unix tree or using an IDE. Doing something with tableofcontents seems quite smart. Ideally there would be a working solution much like there is for wordcount with texcount.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a tool, sorry, but generating a very simple `tree`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newwrite\tvhandle%


\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{mylevel}

\newcommand{\writetv}[3]{%
  \edef\mydef{\space}
  \ifnum #3 > 0
  \foreach \x in {1,...,#3}
  {
    \xdef\mydef{\mydef-}
  }
  \fi
  \immediate\write\tvhandle{\mydef #1 #2}
}

\xapptocmd{\tableofcontents}{%
  \addtocontents{tvaux}{\protect\writetv{}{\contentsname}{0}}%
}{}{}

\xapptocmd{\listoffigures}{%
  \addtocontents{tvaux}{\protect\writetv{}{\listfigurename}{0}}%
}{}{}

\newcommand\starttreeview{%
  \immediate\openout\tvhandle=\jobname.tv
  \@starttoc{tvaux}%
  \immediate\closeout\tvhandle
}

\xpatchcmd{\@sect}{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%
}{%
  \addtocontents{tvaux}{\protect\writetv{\csname the#1\endcsname}{#7}{#2}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
    \fi
    #7}%  
}{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\starttreeview
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\section{first}

\subsection{first}

\subsubsection{first}

\paragraph{first}

\subparagraph{first}

\section{Second}


\subsection{second}

\subsubsection{second}

\paragraph{second}

\subparagraph{second}



\end{document}
```

This produces an unaligned 'tree' (sorry, no figures yet) in the `\jobname.tv` file

```
 Contents
  List of Figures
 -1 first
 --1.1 first
 ---1.1.1 first
 -2 Second
 --2.1 second
 ---2.1.1 second
```

Comment: Patching `\@ssect` would provide the functionality for `\section*` etc. as well -- `\tableofcontents` etc. would make an entry automatically then and do not have to be patched separately.